# Are these infinitives adjectival and adverbial?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

> ① Whatever book you can bring **to** contribute to the library is much appreciated.
>
> ② Whatever book you can bring **to** contribute **it** to the library is much appreciated.

① Any book (to contribute to the library) that you can bring is … ; hence the *to*-infinitive  herein is adjectival.

② Any book that you can bring in order to contribute it to the library is … ; hence the *to*-infinitive   herein is adverbial.

Is my grammatical analysis for #1 and #2 correct?

Comment: _To_ is not an infinitive. Your second sentence sounds quite unnatural, it's difficult to wrap my mind around what you could be trying to say with it.

Comment: I think that a simpler and more natural statement might be something like: "Whatever book you can contribute to the library will be much appreciated".

Answer (score 1):

> Whatever book you can bring to contribute to the library is much appreciated.

This type of sentence contains a special relative construction, which is a bit like a relative clause. It's called a *fused relative*. The structure of this particular sentence is like this:

- [Whatever book you can bring to contribute to the library] is much appreciated.

Here the part in brackets is the fused relative. It is the subject of the sentence. The Original Poster's question is about the structures *inside* the fused relative. In particular we are interested in the function of the infinitival phrase *to contribute*.

If we want to understand the function of *to contribute*, we need to understand the rest of the clause. Like in a normal relative clause the relative word *whatever* is at the front. Here *whatever* is a determiner. It is doing the same job as words like: *a, the, this, that, my, any*. It belongs with the noun *books*. If the determiner is at the front of the clause, its noun must go with it. Here the noun *book* appears after its determiner.

- **Whatever book** you can bring to contribute to the library.

The noun phrase *whatever book* is understood as the object of the verb *bring*. In a normal sentence the object would come after this verb:

- You can bring [whatever book] to contribute to the library.

In the fused relative there is a gap in the clause where we would expect *whatever book* to appear. It has the function of the object of the clause:

- **Whatever book** you can bring  ___ to contribute to the library.

We could understand the clause like this:

- **Whatever book** you can bring  [ <del>that book</del> ] to contribute to the library.

That gap, the place where we expect an object to be, has the same index as *whatever book*. We understand that they refer to the same thing:

- **Whatever book** <sub>(i)</sub> you can bring  ___ <sub>(i)</sub> to contribute to the library.

We will come back and talk about that gap in a second. Before we do that, we need to investigate the *contibute to* phrase. This is an example of an *infinitive of purpose*. It's a special type of 'infinitive of purpose'. Here are some more examples:

- I bought that book **to read** on the train.
- I made some sandwiches **to eat** at lunch.
- My chimpanzee looked for some baboons **to play with**.

Here the infinitival verb phrases *to read on the train*, *to eat during my lunchbreak* and *to play with* are adjuncts. They provide extra information about why I bought the book, made some sandwiches and about why my chimpanzee looked for some baboons.

These clauses are non-finite, they don't have a verb with tense. Instead they have an infinitive form. Because they have no tense, they do not need a full subject. The subject is *unexpressed*. There are no words in these clause which represent the subjects of the verbs *read, eat* or *play*. We don't need them, because we can easily understand who the subject is. There is no grammatical rule about who we understand as the subject of these verbs. In the *sandwiches* sentence, the subject of *eat* might not be me, it might be *everybody*. The sentence might mean:

- I made some sandwiches (for everyone) to eat at lunch.

However, if we look at these clauses carefully, we'll see that they also have no objects.

- I bought that book [ (for me) to read ___ on the train ].
- I made some sandwiches [ (for us) to eat ___ at lunch ].
- My chimpanzee looked for some baboons [ (for her) to play with ___ ].

The way that we interpret these objects *is* because of the grammar. The identity of the object of the infinitive, is the same as the object in the main clause:

- I bought that book<sub>(i)</sub> [ (for me) to read ___<sub>(i)</sub> on the train ].
- I made some sandwiches<sub>(i)</sub> [ (for us) to eat ___<sub>(i)</sub> at lunch ].
- My chimpanzee looked for some baboons<sub>(i)</sub> [ (for her) to play with ___<sub>(i)</sub> ].

We can understand the clauses like this:

- I bought that book [ for me to read that book on the train ].
- I made some sandwiches [ for us to eat those sandwiches at lunch ].
- My chimpanzee looked for some baboons [ for her to play with those baboons ].

In the Original Poster's fused relative, there is an infinitive of purpose like this:

- Whatever book you can bring [to contribute ___ to the library].

We interpret the object of *to contribute* through the object of the main clause: *whatever book you can bring*. Now the object of the main clause is a gap. This gap has the same index as the subject. So we understand the object of *to contribute* like this:

- Whatever book<sub>(i)</sub> you can bring ____<sub>(i)</sub> [ to contribute ___<sub>(i)</sub> to the library ].

In other words:

- Whatever book you can bring [  <del>that book</del>  ] to contribute [  <del>that book</del>  ] to the library.

**The Original Poster's Question**

The Original Poster wanted to know if *to contribute* is modifying the noun *book* ( - some people call this *adjectival* modification),  or if it is modifying the clause *whatever book you can bring* (some people would call this adverbial). The answer is that it is modifying the clause. The infinitival clause is an adjunct explaining why you're going to bring the book.

The Original Poster wonders if the sentence interpretation is something like:

- Any book (to contribute to the library) that you can bring

The answer is: no, I don't think that *to contribute* is modifying *the book* or even a gap that represents the book. This is why: the *to contribute* clause seems to have to explain *why you bring* the book, not the purpose of the book itself.

*Books to read at Christmas* is an example of a noun modified by an infinitive. If we put it in a sentence, but put the infinitive at the end of a clause like the one in the example it won't work. It will read as if the purpose of the book is the reason why the subject did the action:

- *Whatever books you sold to read at Christmas

This phrase doesn't work. This infinitive must explain why you sold the books not what the books are for. In the original example, *to contribute to the library* explains why you will *bring* the book, not what the purpose of the book is. In the original example, these might almost be the same thing, but the grammar seems to show that the *to contribute* clause modifies the whole of the main clause.

The Original Poster also wonders whether *it* changes the structure of the fused relative. The answer is that we really need to leave out the object at the end of this type of infinitive if the object of the main clause is a gap:

- What food did you bring to eat?
- *what food did you bring to eat it? (wrong).

Here are those sentences again with the gaps:

- What food did you bring ____<sub>(i)</sub> to eat ____<sub>(i)</sub> ?
- *What food did you bring ____<sub>(i)</sub> to eat it<sub>(i)</sub>? (wrong)

I hope this helps!

Comment: @F.E. Yes, Ive reconsidered. I think if the object isn't a gap its marginal: *I bought those sweets to eat them* is not good, but marginal (with the right intonation). However, *which sweets did you buy to eat them* is very bad - I think, having done some experimentation, it's because the object of the main clause is a gap ... What d'you think? I agree with your obs, and have amended. Thanks:)

Comment: About the "resumptive pronoun" (in the hollow purpose infinitival), I'm thinking this issue is probably the same as with the resumptive pronoun in a relative clause. That is, the longer the sentence is, the more involved it is, then the less bad that use of using the resumptive pronoun becomes, and in nonstandard speech, a speaker might insert that pronoun in there to add clarity to what they are saying. But for today's English, it's probably nonstandard: for if it was standard, then I would've hoped that CGEL would've mentioned using the pronoun to disambiguate the examples on page 1067 [4].